# How to add data values of end points on line chart and the percentage change next to the chart header?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have the following data frame (df1) and its corresponding `ggplot2` line chart. My `R` codes stand as follows:

```
codes_list <- read.csv("codes_list.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

inner_join(df1, codes_list, by = c('ticker' = 'code')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~desc, scales = 'free_y')
```

"codes_list.csv" is a look up file for the tickers abbreviations found in `df1`.

An extract of `df1` is given below:

```
price.close      ticker    ref.date
  18.01           AAN      2020-12-21
  17.13           AAN      2020-12-22
  16.75           AAN      2020-12-23
  16.78           AAN      2020-12-24
  65.62           CROX     2020-12-21
  64.76           CROX     2020-12-21
  64.59           CROX     2020-12-21
  62.59           CROX     2020-12-21
```

An extract of the `gplot2` chart is shown below.

[image: screenshot 1]

I would like to add the following on the line chart:

1. the starting value and its corresponding ending value
2. the % change next to the line chart header

Expected output is shown below:

[image: screenshot 2]

How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `arrange` the data by `ticker` and `ref.date`, add percent change in the ticker value, create a new `label` column keeping only 1st and last value and plot the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(ref.date = as.Date(ref.date)) %>%
  arrange(ticker, ref.date) %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(ticker = paste(ticker, round((last(price.close) - 
                  first(price.close))/last(price.close) * 100, 2), '%'), 
         label = replace(round(price.close,2), -c(1, n()), '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = ref.date, y = price.close, label = label)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_text() + 
  facet_wrap(~ticker, scales = 'free_y')
```

Based on your actual data you may need to adjust the position of labels in `geom_text` using parameters like `hjust`, `vjust`, `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I show the values on the line chart at 2 decimal places?

Comment: Which values? I think label already shows data at 2 decimal places? Do you need to change the y-axis value?

Comment: The values at the endpoints on the line chart. I have some values being shown at 6 decimal places (the data in my example are hard coded and is only an extract).